# Bit operator AND does not return a value

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation

So I have this code:

```vb
Dim a As Byte = (1 << 1)
Dim b As Byte = (1 << 2)
Dim c As Byte = (1 << 3)

Dim res As Byte
res = a And b And c
```

The result (`res`) is 0. Why? I just want to manipulate the bits in this, but the return value is always 0. All tutorials show me, that this should work. Some do something like `Dim a As Byte = 2`, but shouldn't it be unimportant how to set the value of a byte?
My debugger also shows me that the bytes `a`, `b` and `c` are set correctly. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

It was a huge mistake on my side. I knew that I needed to use the `OR` operator but didnt. I just had a big brain lag. Excuse me for being this impatient and not thinking this over properly. I will leave this question here so maybe someone sees that this is his/her problem, too.
Again, please excuse me.

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  The AND operator only produces a 1 bit if the variables have a 1 in common.  They don't.  This brain-bug is hard to reverse-engineer when you don't explain what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the result of `2 and 4 and 8` is 0. None of those numbers have any binary columnar digits in common:

```
2 is 0010
4 is 0100
8 is 1000
```

AND works down the column and only records a 1 in the result if all the values in the column are 1:

```
3 AND 5

     3 is 0011
     5 is 0101
result is 0001
             ^ only this column has all 1s in it.
```

The result of `3 And 5` is `1`

---

> All tutorials show me, that this should work

Show us those tutorials, so we can better understand what is going wrong in the process of `the_tutorial --> your_brain` - one or the other parts of that operation has an error! :)

Comment: Damn I had a huge brain lag. Of course I need the `OR` operator. I knew that, but somehow I didnt. It was a huge fail on my side. Please excuse my stupidity. Thank you for your answer anyways!

Comment: No problems! Sometimes we just "can't see the wood for the trees" :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you don't actually understand what the bitwise `And` operator does. Zero is exactly what you should expect from that code. You should have told us this in the first place but what do you expect and why? I suspect that you actually want the `Or` operator rather than `And`. Regardless, you should read up and learn what those bitwise operators actually do. It might also help to look at those values in a more obvious way:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As Byte = (1 << 1)
        Dim b As Byte = (1 << 2)
        Dim c As Byte = (1 << 3)

        Display(a)
        Display(b)
        Display(c)
        Display(a And b And c)
        Display(a Or b Or c)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Display(b As Byte)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c))
    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000000100
00000000000000000000000000001000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000001110
```

Comment: Same comment to you as for Caius. Please excuse my stupidity. Of course I need the `OR` operator. I knew that, but didnt do it. That was a big fail on my side.
Thank you for your answer, anyways!